# python invalid json format

Tags: python, json

I am pulling data with rest api with below script but output data is not valid for json. I cannot see it in jsonviewer. Do you have any idea how to fix it?

```
headers = {
    "cookie": "JSESSIONID=node07z8uqc8xfd776gx6z7wslnoy4708978.node0",
    "Authorization": "Basic SElBQV9HVUlfUmVwb3J0OlB3MiN6MjdLWmxJam16TFFIYTFv",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, json=payload, headers=headers, params=querystring, verify=False)

res=response.json()
```

output:

```
{'status': {'total': 1, 'matched': 1, 'processed': 1, 'completed': True, 'aborted': False, 'hasErrors': False}, 'result': [{'signature': 'raidOwner#33414-SACONC1ANKT', 'syn_raidLdev_transferRate': [{'type': 'timeseries', 'name': 'Transfer Rate', 'unit': 'KB/s', 'interval': 300, 'start': '20210627_230500', 'data': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}]}, {'signature': 'raidOwner#33414-TCTMDELLVMPL07_PROBE', 'syn_raidLdev_transferRate': [{'type': 'timeseries', 'name': 'Transfer Rate', 'unit': 'KB/s', 'interval': 300, 'start': '20210627_230500', 'data': [18, 47, 47, 47, 44, 47, 52, 51, 47, 48, 47, 46]}]}, {'signature': 'raidOwner#33414-BUTTE14', 'syn_raidLdev_transferRate': [{'type': 'timeseries', 'name': 'Transfer Rate', 'unit': 'KB/s', 'interval': 300, 'start': '20210627_230500', 'data': [281, 50, 41, 67, 211, 62, 45, 57, 35, 51, 41, 36]}]}, {'signature': 'raidOwner#33414-SADEC1ANKT', 'syn_raidLdev_transferRate': [{'type': 'timeseries', 'name': 'Transfer Rate', 'unit': 'KB/s', 'interval': 300, 'start': '20210627_230500', 'data': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}]}, {'signature': 'raidOwner#33414-TMMENGEN', 'syn_raidLdev_transferRate': [{'type': 'timeseries', 'name': 'Transfer Rate', 'unit': 'KB/s', 'interval': 300, 'start': '20210627_230500', 'data': [7, 10, 3, 7, 10, 7, 6, 7, 7, 10, 3, 10]}]}, {'signature': 'raidOwner#33414-UYGURWANK01_-1_2', 'syn_raidLdev_transferRate': [{'type': 'timeseries', 'name': 'Transfer Rate', 'unit': 'KB/s', 'interval': 300, 'start': '20210627_230500', 'data': [8, 3, 3, 9, 6, 3, 0, 6, 6, 13, 6, 9]}]}, {'signature': 'raidOwner#33414-HISARVIO', 'syn_raidLdev_transferRate': [{'type': 'timeseries', 'name': 'Transfer Rate', 'unit': 'KB/s', 'interval': 300, 'start': '20210627_230500', 'data': [187, 202, 148, 195, 186, 166, 165, 161, 169, 205, 179, 175]}]}, {'signature': 'raidOwner#33414-TDMTMLTEST08', 'syn_raidLdev_transferRate': [{'type': 'timeseries', 'name': 'Transfer Rate', 'unit': 'KB/s', 'interval': 300, 'start': '20210627_230500', 'data': [721, 158, 144, 126, 138, 708, 304, 138, 203, 951, 144, 153]}]}, {'signature': 'raidOwner#33414-ARCWAYODM', 'syn_raidLdev_transferRate': [{'type': 'timeseries', 'name': 'Transfer Rate', 'unit': 'KB/s', 'interval': 300, 'start': '20210627_230500', 'data': [4675, 9151, 9572, 2909, 12598, 38262, 21859, 7810, 10647, 3113, 7722, 9493]}]}, {'signature': 'raidOwner#33414-COLUMBIAODM', 'syn_raidLdev_transferRate': [{'type': 'timeseries', 'name': 'Transfer Rate', 'unit': 'KB/s', 'interval': 300, 'start': '20210627_230500', 'data': [9863, 4897, 5928, 8630, 4940, 5189, 8824, 5612, 6019, 7568, 5822, 5311]}]}, {'signature': 'raidOwner#33414-PATRIOTODM', 'syn_raidLdev_transferRate': [{'type': 'timeseries', 'name': 'Transfer Rate', 'unit': 'KB/s', 'interval': 300, 'start': '20210627_230500', 'data': [32157, 17399, 25190, 34330, 31522, 26501, 33375, 16874, 33765, 15966, 16775, 38235]}]}, {'signature': 'raidOwner#33414-PAPELODM', 'syn_raidLdev_transferRate': [{'type': 'timeseries', 'name': 'Transfer Rate', 'unit': 'KB/s', 'interval': 300, 'start': '20210627_230500', 'data': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}]}, {'signature': 'raidOwner#33414-EXPERIAODM2', 'syn_raidLdev_transferRate': [{'type': 'timeseries', 'name': 'Transfer Rate', 'unit': 'KB/s', 'interval': 300, 'start': '20210627_230500', 'data': [242376, 656037, 580521, 548083, 533699, 431400, 269603, 243191, 162227, 120463, 119748, 204799]}]}, {'signature': 'raidOwner#33414-BTEST10', 'syn_raidLdev_transferRate': [{'type': 'timeseries', 'name': 'Transfer Rate', 'unit': 'KB/s', 'interval': 300, 'start': '20210627_230500', 'data': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}]}, {'signature': 'raidOwner#33414-PAY1ODM', 'syn_raidLdev_transferRate': [{'type': 'timeseries', 'name': 'Transfer Rate', 'unit': 'KB/s', 'interval': 300, 'start': '20210627_230500', 'data': [7, 3, 3, 7, 3, 3, 7, 3, 3, 7, 3, 7]}]}, {'signature': 'raidOwner#33414-BUTTE26', 'syn_raidLdev_transferRate': [{'type': 'timeseries', 'name': 'Transfer Rate', 'unit': 'KB/s', 'interval': 300, 'start': '20210627_230500', 'data': [56760, 86203, 94584, 65130, 61539, 82702, 60885, 69314, 94918, 27351, 54816, 27491]}]}, {'signature': 'raidOwner#33414-FROGODM', 'syn_raidLdev_transferRate': [{'type': 'timeseries', 'name': 'Transfer Rate', 'unit': 'KB/s', 'interval': 300, 'start': '20210627_230500', 'data': [2224526, 2393403, 1590811, 1312885, 1089164, 1016038, 1149478, 926692, 995665, 1241744, 1017906, 1188569]}]}, {'signature': 'raidOwner#33414-BUTTE08', 'syn_raidLdev_transferRate': [{'type': 'timeseries', 'name': 'Transfer Rate', 'unit': 'KB/s', 'interval': 300, 'start': '20210627_230500', 'data': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}]}, {'signature': 'raidOwner#33414-KACKARSNP2', 'syn_raidLdev_transferRate': [{'type': 'timeseries', 'name': 'Transfer Rate', 'unit': 'KB/s', 'interval': 300, 'start': '20210627_230500', 'data': [4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]}]}, {'signature': 'raidOwner#33414-KACKARSNP1', 'syn_raidLdev_transferRate': [{'type': 'timeseries', 'name': 'Transfer Rate', 'unit': 'KB/s', 'interval': 300, 'start': '20210627_230500', 'data': [4, 3, 3, 3, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]}]}, {'signature': 'raidOwner#33414-KACKARSI', 'syn_raidLdev_transferRate': [{'type': 'timeseries', 'name': 'Transfer Rate', 'unit': 'KB/s', 'interval': 300, 'start': '20210627_230500', 'data': [4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]}]}, {'signature': 'raidOwner#33414-KACKARDEV', 'syn_raidLdev_transferRate': [{'type': 'timeseries', 'name': 'Transfer Rate', 'unit': 'KB/s', 'interval': 300, 'start': '20210627_230500', 'data': [4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 3, 7]}]}, {'signature': 'raidOwner#33414-NIMCELL', 'syn_raidLdev_transferRate': [{'type': 'timeseries', 'name': 'Transfer Rate', 'unit': 'KB/s', 'interval': 300, 'start': '20210627_230500', 'data': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}]}, {'signature': 'raidOwner#33414-TMFILYOS01', 'syn_raidLdev_transferRate': [{'type': 'timeseries', 'name': 'Transfer Rate', 'unit': 'KB/s', 'interval': 300, 'start': '20210627_230500', 'data': [131, 123, 119, 130, 120, 119, 127, 122, 119, 130, 119, 121]}]}, {'signature': 'raidOwner#33414-KACKARST', 'syn_raidLdev_transferRate': [{'type': 'timeseries', 'name': 'Transfer Rate', 'unit': 'KB/s', 'interval': 300, 'start': '20210627_230500', 'data': [4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]}]}, {'signature': 'raidOwner#33414-ACTONODM', 'syn_raidLdev_transferRate': [{'type': 'timeseries', 'name': 'Transfer Rate', 'unit': 'KB/s', 'interval': 300, 'start': '20210627_230500', 'data': [18, 14, 14, 17, 14, 14, 17, 14, 14, 24, 14, 13]}]}, {'signature': 'raidOwner#33414-BUTTE04', 'syn_raidLdev_transferRate': [{'type': 'timeseries', 'name': 'Transfer Rate', 'unit': 'KB/s', 'interval': 300, 'start': '20210627_230500', 'data': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}]}, {'signature': 'raidOwner#33414-KACKARPRP', 'syn_raidLdev_transferRate': [{'type': 'timeseries', 'name': 'Transfer Rate', 'unit': 'KB/s', 'interval': 300, 'start': '20210627_230500', 'data': [7, 3, 3, 7, 3, 3, 7, 3, 3, 3, 7, 3]}]}, {'signature': 'raidOwner#33414-TMFILYOS0-1_2', 'syn_raidLdev_transferRate': [{'type': 'timeseries', 'name': 'Transfer Rate', 'unit': 'KB/s', 'interval': 300, 'start': '20210627_230500', 'data': [47, 30, 43, 27, 34, 40, 34, 38, 31, 40, 34, 27]}]}, {'signature': 'raidOwner#33414-GIOVANNIODM', 'syn_raidLdev_transferRate': [{'type': 'timeseries', 'name': 'Transfer Rate', 'unit': 'KB/s', 'interval': 300, 'start': '20210627_230500', 'data': [38986, 41206, 99873, 168996, 173111, 45839, 11291, 10436, 21897, 10855, 11033, 14073]}]}, {'signature': 'raidOwner#33414-AXMB26', 'syn_raidLdev_transferRate': [{'type': 'timeseries', 'name': 'Transfer Rate', 'unit': 'KB/s', 'interval': 300, 'start': '20210627_230500', 'data': [19551, 18129, 18708, 16765, 16456, 21697, 25549, 20731, 21459, 17117, 15462, 18972]}]}, {'signature': 'raidOwner#33414-AXMB25', 'syn_raidLdev_transferRate': [{'type': 'timeseries', 'name': 'Transfer Rate', 'unit': 'KB/s', 'interval': 300, 'start': '20210627_230500', 'data': [15130, 13918, 14320, 13455, 12740, 20026, 21771, 14503, 14235, 13461, 13559, 16014]}]}, {'signature': 'raidOwner#33414-AXMB24', 'syn_raidLdev_transferRate': [{'type': 'timeseries', 'name': 'Transfer Rate', 'unit': 'KB/s', 'interval': 300, 'start': '20210627_230500', 'data': [16575, 15983, 19261, 23725, 16914, 15068, 15720, 15878, 15094, 14545, 13987, 15707]}]}, {'signature': 'raidOwner#33414-AXMB23', 'syn_raidLdev_transferRate': [{'type': 'timeseries', 'name': 'Transfer Rate', 'unit': 'KB/s', 'interval': 300, 'start': '20210627_230500', 'data': [25051, 22608, 21930, 21603, 21612, 21932, 21839, 20880, 22166, 19543, 19857, 20422]}]}, {'signature': 'raidOwner#33414-ULTIADB03', 'syn_raidLdev_transferRate': [{'type': 'timeseries', 'name': 'Transfer Rate', 'unit': 'KB/s', 'interval': 300, 'start': '20210627_230500', 'data': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}]}, {'signature': 'raidOwner#33414-AXMB22', 'syn_raidLdev_transferRate': [{'type': 'timeseries', 'name': 'Transfer Rate', 'unit': 'KB/s', 'interval': 300, 'start': '20210627_230500', 'data': [21042, 21118, 20551, 19350, 20186, 20724, 20651, 21685, 20426, 21073, 20949, 21873]}]}, {'signature': 'raidOwner#33414-MONOODM', 'syn_raidLdev_transferRate': [{'type': 'timeseries', 'name': 'Transfer Rate', 'unit': 'KB/s', 'interval': 300, 'start': '20210627_230500', 'data': [653882, 578192, 601919, 584437, 441061, 376242, 462738, 434533, 513835, 678884, 536437, 453086]}]}, {'signature': 'raidOwner#33414-POTASYUM02', 'syn_raidLdev_transferRate': [{'type': 'timeseries', 'name': 'Transfer Rate', 'unit': 'KB/s', 'interval': 300, 'start': '20210627_230500', 'data': [1056, 1417, 942, 847, 1363, 970, 1086, 1038, 945, 836, 1174, 1086]}]}, {'signature': 'raidOwner#33414-AXMB21', 'syn_raidLdev_transferRate': [{'type': 'timeseries', 'name': 'Transfer Rate', 'unit': 'KB/s', 'interval': 300, 'start': '20210627_230500', 'data': [4831, 6172, 8309, 5106, 4622, 5239, 4637, 5695, 5355, 6042, 5024, 5472]}]}, {'signature': 'raidOwner#33414-AXMB20', 'syn_raidLdev_transferRate': [{'type': 'timeseries', 'name': 'Transfer Rate', 'unit': 'KB/s', 'interval': 300, 'start': '20210627_230500', 'data': [6482, 7090, 8353, 6121, 5609, 6338, 7364, 7165, 6522, 6442, 5375, 5910]}]}, {'signature': 'raidOwner#33414-TROIAODM_-DATA_OTHER', 'syn_raidLdev_transferRate': [{'type': 'timeseries', 'name': 'Transfer Rate', 'unit': 'KB/s', 'interval': 300, 'start': '20210627_230500', 'data': [232920, 288949, 1033782, 670121, 1241934, 215641, 708520, 321912, 123164, 556778, 651439, 208483]}]}, {'signature': 'raidOwner#33414-MAXIMUSODM', 'syn_raidLdev_transferRate': [{'type': 'timeseries', 'name': 'Transfer Rate', 'unit': 'KB/s', 'interval': 300, 'start': '20210627_230500', 'data': [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 10, 7, 3, 7, 7, 7]}]}, {'signature': 'raidOwner#33414-CACA2', 'syn_raidLdev_transferRate': [{'type': 'timeseries', 'name': 'Transfer Rate', 'unit': 'KB/s', 'interval': 300, 'start': '20210627_230500', 'data': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}]}, {'signature': 'raidOwner#33414-TMLBIBOPODM', 'syn_raidLdev_transferRate': [{'type': 'timeseries', 'name': 'Transfer Rate', 'unit': 'KB/s', 'interval': 300, 'start': '20210627_230500', 'data': [3330, 7786, 5519, 3111, 3957, 4372, 4061, 3852, 5314, 2888, 4494, 4486]}]}, {'signature': 'raidOwner#33414-ASCEND04', 'syn_raidLdev_transferRate': [{'type': 'timeseries', 'name': 'Transfer Rate', 'unit': 'KB/s', 'interval': 300, 'start': '20210627_230500', 'data': [139, 129, 102, 115, 113, 91, 132, 132, 126, 106, 91, 92]}]}, {'signature': 'raidOwner#33414-KACKARDAY', 'syn_raidLdev_transferRate': [{'type': 'timeseries', 'name': 'Transfer Rate', 'unit': 'KB/s', 'interval': 300, 'start': '20210627_230500', 'data': [7, 3, 7, 3, 7, 7, 3, 10, 3, 7, 3, 7]}]}, {'signature': 'raidOwner#33414-GORELE3', 'syn_raidLdev_transferRate': [{'type': 'timeseries', 'name': 'Transfer Rate', 'unit': 'KB/s', 'interval': 300, 'start': '20210627_230500', 'data': [2197, 2065, 3256, 2220, 1789, 1085, 5257, 2072, 1785, 2224, 2466, 1346]}]}, {'signature': 'raidOwner#33414-MAXIMUSODM_ULTIMAODM', 'syn_raidLdev_transferRate': [{'type': 'timeseries', 'name': 'Transfer Rate', 'unit': 'KB/s', 'interval': 300, 'start': '20210627_230500', 'data': [1192, 699, 2037, 780, 677, 1472, 1264, 728, 1504, 855, 799, 1500]}]}, {'signature': 'raidOwner#33414-ULTIMAODM', 'syn_raidLdev_transferRate': [{'type': 'timeseries', 'name': 'Transfer Rate', 'unit': 'KB/s', 'interval': 300, 'start': '20210627_230500', 'data': [224369, 32483, 36993, 37510, 30518, 37591, 48513, 29792, 45712, 30970, 32095, 32290]}]}, {'signature': 'raidOwner#33414-ASCEND03', 'syn_raidLdev_transferRate': [{'type': 'timeseries', 'name': 'Transfer Rate', 'unit': 'KB/s', 'interval': 300, 'start': '20210627_230500', 'data': [156, 122, 96, 118, 112, 91, 127, 132, 126, 110, 98, 92]}]}, {'signature': 'raidOwner#33414-JAGUARWANK11', 'syn_raidLdev_transferRate': [{'type': 'timeseries', 'name': 'Transfer Rate', 'unit': 'KB/s', 'interval': 300, 'start': '20210627_230500', 'data': [2314, 1034, 8468, 2153, 1189, 894, 232, 344, 170, 4037, 232, 782]}]}, {'signature': 'raidOwner#33414-BUTTE01', 'syn_raidLdev_transferRate': [{'type': 'timeseries', 'name': 'Transfer Rate', 'unit': 'KB/s', 'interval': 300, 'start': '20210627_230500', 'data': [1814, 1609, 1279, 1394, 1320, 1249, 2002, 1329, 1270, 1359, 1284, 3383]}]}, {'signature': 'raidOwner#33414-TMFILYOS02', 'syn_raidLdev_transferRate': [{'type': 'timeseries', 'name': 'Transfer Rate', 'unit': 'KB/s', 'interval': 300, 'start': '20210627_230500', 'data': [109, 109, 113, 109, 110, 112, 116, 116, 123, 113, 116, 114]}]}, {'signature': 'raidOwner#33414-RUFFLESODM', 'syn_raidLdev_transferRate': [{'type': 'timeseries', 'name': 'Transfer Rate', 'unit': 'KB/s', 'interval': 300, 'start': '20210627_230500', 'data': [176860, 16445, 3234, 20159, 7399, 3638, 716597, 5550, 3403, 13726, 2837, 4777]}]}, {'signature': 'raidOwner#33414-TMGEREDE', 'syn_raidLdev_transferRate': [{'type': 'timeseries', 'name': 'Transfer Rate', 'unit': 'KB/s', 'interval': 300, 'start': '20210627_230500', 'data': [4, 7, 10, 7, 6, 7, 7, 6, 7, 10, 3, 7]}]}, {'signature': 'raidOwner#33414-SREDMMAPP5', 'syn_raidLdev_transferRate': [{'type': 'timeseries', 'name': 'Transfer Rate', 'unit': 'KB/s', 'interval': 300, 'start': '20210627_230500', 'data': [0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0]}]}]}
```

Comment: It looks like you've got a perfectly valid Python object, created from perfectly valid json. Whatever you put into you viewer probably wasn't the original text it expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the method name to retrieve the response as "JSON" and not as text is `.json()`, the output itself is not JSON but  `<class 'dict'>`.
Therefore you need to `import json` and use `json.dumps(res.json())` in order to convert this dictionary to 'legal' JSON, and then you will be able to see it in jsonviewer.

In addition, you can also just use `res.text` instead of `json.dumps(res.json())`, since the text is legal JSON.

Comment: Or, just use `response.text`

Comment: @MarkTolonen sure, i forgot at all about it :D